# http/1.1 compliant way to request body only

Tags: http

Is there a way, that is compliant with http/1.1, to request the body only?

I believe http/0.9 allowed for "GET /\r\n\r\n" which returns the body only.

I am trying to future proof a PLC application that generates a hand made HTTP request. It would be very useful to not deal with the response headers.

Comment: Why do you ask? Why can't you use some *existing* HTTP library (e.g. [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) on server side, [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) on client side)? The answer is probably no! Smells like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info); and you always need the `Content-Type` of the body, so you *need* to parse response headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that.